# Why can I store a callable target in a std::function which dosen't match the type

Tags: c++, c++11, stdbind

I have tried the following:

```
typedef std::function<void(int)> callback;

struct testclass
{
    void testfunc()
    {
        printf("test\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    testclass test;
    callback c = std::bind(&testclass::testfunc, &test);
    c(1);
}
```

The output is

```
test
```

The `std::bind` returns a callable target like `void(void)`, while the callback should be stored a `void(int)`.

Why can I do this?

Comment: Probably because bind returns `A function object of unspecified type`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::bind` gives you back a function object that ignores any argument that doesn't have an associated placeholder. It's a loose match.

For instance:

```
auto f = []{}; // no arguments, do nothing
f(1); // obviously ill-formed

auto g = std::bind(f);
g(); // okay, calls f()
g(1); // okay, calls f()
g(1, 2); // okay, calls f()
```

In your example, you have a `function<void(int)>` that you're initializing with the result of a `std::bind()` call without placeholders. That works fine. The `int` argument of the `function` just gets ignored. It may or may not be what you actually want to do, but it's perfectly valid code.

---

With a lambda, you could get the same effect by writing:

```
callback c = [&test](int){ test.testfunc(); };
```

Here we have to explicitly write the parameter though, whereas with `bind` it was implicitly ignored.